# run a php function from js

Tags: javascript, php, html

end goal: HTML element is click i want to run PHP functions

so i want to do something like this

```
  function byeBye(page) {
    if (page == 'teacher.php') {
      <?php $_SESSION['AccType'] = 1; ?>
    } else if (page == 'admin.php') {
      <?php $_SESSION['AccType'] = 2; ?>
    }
    console.log('Redirecting to ' + page);
    window.location.href = './' + page;
  }
</script>
```

and it called with something like this
`<li id='admin' class="list-group-item" onclick="byeBye('admin.php')">`
but you can see what is wrong with that. what is the right way to do this?

Comment: You need to understand that javascript is executed on the client side (in the browser), while php is executed on the server side. You cannot simply call a function, because those are completely separate systems. You need to make an ajax request from the client to the server. You will find many examples for that here on SO or on google.

Comment: It seems, you are using PHP only to set the session, right?

Comment: thats correct. thats all i need it to do

Comment: Some good reading: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: i do get the difreance its just that I don't see any way to do what I want without js

Comment: As others have said, PHP and JS are separate systems. If your code is as simple as that, why don't you set a session on the destination page?

Comment: because the next page will have something like [this](https://pastebin.com/6nhyQxtS) I only want the user if it has the session var

Comment: You should set that session value on login, depending on the user. Anything that could change the user type from the client side would be unsecure.